# Tkinter radio buttons always gives values of 0

Tags: python, tkinter, radio-button, spyder

I'm trying to use radio buttons to define a variable to be used in the rest of my script.

When I run this code, shift is always 0.

I have copied and pasted code from online doing something similar, but the values are always 0.

I am using Spyder to run python3.

Thanks.

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

def pixelShift():
        shift = var.get()
        print(shift)

var = IntVar()

Radiobutton(root,
            text        = '1 Pixel',
            variable    = var,
            value       = 1,
            command     = pixelShift
            ).pack(anchor = W)

Radiobutton(root,
            text        = '10 Pixels',
            variable    = var,
            value       = 10,
            command     = pixelShift
            ).pack(anchor = W)

Radiobutton(root,
            text        = '100 Pixel',
            variable    = var,
            value       = 100,
            command     = pixelShift
            ).pack(anchor = W)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Maybe it's a problem with spyder? When I run your code from the command line it all works fine. Have you tried saving references to the radiobuttons? (eg: `rb1 = Radiobutton(...)`, `rb2 = ...`, `rb3 = ...`)

Comment: Most probably there are more than one instance of `Tk()`.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a new `Tk()` instance by using

```
var = IntVar()
```

You should use

```
root = Toplevel()
```

or

```
var = IntVar(root)
```